# Can Luhn (credit card number hashing) be implemented without external/custom functions in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, check-constraints, luhn

Stripping off the last digit of a string and reversing it... these vary a bit from Postgres to Oracle to whatever, but are easily accomplished.

This query fragment is about halfway there:

```
select translate(reverse(left('6011406981867628',-1)), '13579', '26159');
-- 6011406981867628 is a fake credit card number for test purposes.
```

The only thing left is to sum all the digits, and then mod 10 them. However, when I attempt that with:

```
select sum(regexp_split_to_table(translate(reverse(left('6011406981867628',-1)), '13579', '26159'), E'\\s*')::integer);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
```

Mind you, if I remove the sum, as such:

```
select regexp_split_to_table(translate(reverse(left('6011406981867628',-1)), '13579', '26159'), E'\\s*')::integer;
```

I'll get this:

```
regexp_split_to_table 
-----------------------
                 2
                 6
                 5
                 6
                 8
                 2
                 8
                 9
                 6
                 0
                 4
                 2
                 2
                 0
                 6
(15 rows)
```

If I can come up with the sum, then it's just `check (n%10 = right('6011406981867628',1))` and I'm done.

Is it possible to do the sum() on these?

Comment: Mod 10 serves _no purpose_ except to check for typos -- it should be implemented as close to the presentation layer as possible. Why are you using it as a check constraint?

Comment: I disagree. If I wanted half-assed database ideas, I'd be using Mongo. Maybe my app won't be the only one to access the database directly, and whatever else does will then be able to insert bad data. Everything blows up. There's a reason why Postgres implemented constraints (which is, amusingly, related to why MySQL didn't for so long... it's a smart thing to do). In any event, I'd never personally store credit card numbers in any of my stuff... working on a mod for Sequelize that puts the validators into the backend as well. Hence why I can't just create a function to handle this.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, constraints are important. It's *this* particular constraint that bothers me because it doesn't prove anything. Credit card numbers cannot be known to be _valid_ until they've been run through a payment processing network -- and _good_ cards are a small subset of _valid_ responses.

Comment: Another aside: I'd be double checking that relevant regulations let you store plain-text credit card numbers in your database. Many require data to be encrypted at rest as well as in transit.

Comment: Go look at Sequelize. It has a "isCreditCard" validator. All I want to do is be able to implement the same validation on the backend. I'm not storing any credit cards... that's just asking for heartache in the form of liability. All I want to do is run that same check in both places for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

> Can Luhn (credit card number hashing) be implemented without external/custom functions in Postgres?

Yes, it can, as documented here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

To address your specific question around `SUM`, you're giving it the wrong type of argument. You can do it using a subquery:

```
# select SUM(regexp_split_to_table) from (select regexp_split_to_table(translate(reverse(left('6011406981867628',-1)), '13579', '26159'), E'\\s*')::integer) a;
 sum
-----
  66
(1 row)
```

Comment: Or by "custom function" do you mean avoiding `CREATE_FUNCTION`? Sorry, not clear to me. You can just inline those definitions though.

Comment: Yes, I can't really create a function for this. The built-ins are ok.

Comment: And for that matter, I can't use a subquery, it has to be a plain expression or the check constraint will balk.

Comment: ah, didn't realise you were going for a check constraint. Maybe need to use a trigger instead?

Comment: Can't do a trigger either. I get to place a string at the end of a column definition in a table. I don't have anything other than the standard set of built-in functions (but if there's one of those that's useful, it's great). Your answer is definitely on the right track though.